# Timer in Drools Fusion not working

Tags: drools, drools-fusion

I am trying to run following rules in Drool Fusion( Version 5.4.1 ), but it's not working.

Ideally it should print "HELLO WORLD" every 7 seconds, it's not even triggering once.

Can anybody please help me to understand the timer in Drools?

> ```
>      import com.drools.message.Message
>
> rule "Test" 
>     timer(int: 7s 7s)
> when
>     message:Message (type=="Hello")
> then
>     System.out.println("Hello World, Drools! " + message.getMsgtext());
> end
> ```

```
   My code to run the above Rule is:
```

> ```
> public class TestDrools {
>
>   private static String DRL_FILE = "test_drools.drl";
>   private static KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory
>           .newKnowledgeBuilder();
>   private static Collection pkgs;
>   private static KnowledgeBase kbase = KnowledgeBaseFactory
>           .newKnowledgeBase();
>   private static StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession;
>
>   private static WorkingMemoryEntryPoint entryPoint;
>
>   public static void main(String[] args) {
>       init();
>       while (true) {
>           Message msg = new Message();
>           msg.setType("Hello");
>           msg.setMsgtext("1");
>           ksession.insert(msg);
>       }
>   }
>
>   private static void init() {
>       initialiseDrools();
>   }
>
>   private static void initialiseDrools() {
>       kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource(DRL_FILE),
>               ResourceType.DRL);
>       if (kbuilder.hasErrors()) {
>           System.out.println(kbuilder.getErrors().toString());
>           throw new RuntimeException("Unable to compile drl\".");
>       }
>       pkgs = kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages();
>       KnowledgeBaseConfiguration config = KnowledgeBaseFactory
>               .newKnowledgeBaseConfiguration();
>       config.setOption(EventProcessingOption.STREAM);
>       kbase = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase(config);
>       kbase.addKnowledgePackages(pkgs);
>       KnowledgeSessionConfiguration conf = KnowledgeBaseFactory
>               .newKnowledgeSessionConfiguration();
>       conf.setOption(ClockTypeOption.get("pseudo"));
>       ksession = kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession(conf, null);
>       entryPoint = ksession.getWorkingMemoryEntryPoint("entryone");
>       new Thread() {
>           @Override
>           public void run() {
>               ksession.fireUntilHalt();
>           }
>       }.start();
>   }
> }
> ```

Thank you
-Sanjay

Comment: I take it you're running fireUntilHalt()? It might be worth showing your API code.

Comment: new Thread() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
    ksession.fireUntilHalt();
   }
  }.start();
 }

Comment: You aren't using a pseudo-clock by any chance?

Comment: I have edited the post to add code I am using to test the rule.

Answer (score 1):

As per @laune's comment, you've used the [`pseudo clock`](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.3.0.Final/drools-fusion-docs/html_single/). If you want to use the `realtime` clock, change the following line:

```
  conf.setOption(ClockTypeOption.get("realtime"));
```

Or just remove the line altogether - `realtime` is the default clock.

If you want to use the pseudo clock, you'll need to advance it yourself. This is typically use in unit testing, e.g.

```
  SessionPseudoClock  clock = ksession.getSessionClock();
  // insert some facts ... 
  clock.advanceTime(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
  ksession().fireAllRules();

  // Do your unit test asserts / verify mocks here to verify that 
  // time-reasoned rules were / weren't fired
```

Comment: Note that, in general, alternative inserts and andvances executed in a separate thread, in parallel to the one can be used, too. -- Or the sequence posted by Stuart: advance/[insert/advance/fire can be executed repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

`then` condition happens when `when` condition fulfills,so you need to  at least put `eval(true)` in `when condition` and trigger an insert into `knowledgeSession` so that the rule engine figure out what to do when some condition  fulfills.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried using "when eval(true)", but it's the same issue. If my understanding is right, by default with empty 'when' block means eval(true), correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yeah blank do means eval(true), but are you doing something that insert fact and trigger the rule runtime?

Comment: Yes, I am inserting custom Messages as fact into the session, which should trigger the rule. One more thing if I remove the timer, it works perfect, not sure what's happening with the timer.